# Fetch content of HTML page using python requests dependig on Content-Type?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Using the Python requests library, is there a way to fetch the HTTP response headers and only fetch the body over the network when the Content-Type header is some specific type?

I can of course issue a HEAD request, inspect the Content-Type and if the type matches, issue a GET request. But is there a way to avoid fetching the HTTP headers twice?

Answer (score 0):

I choose to do `requests.head()`, inspect the content-type and if the type is something that should be fetched, do `requests.get()` to get the body.

The extra network I/O of fetching headers twice is outweighed by not fetching bodies of other content types.